# What is the meaning of "at the right angles to each other" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> On the idea of whether the quantum multiverse is the same as the inflationary multiverse . . . I heard
>   this proposed by Leonard Susskind, one of the inventors of string theory at Stanford. I was talking to
>   Steven Weinberg, who is the father of the standard model of particle physics, probably the greatest
>   physicist living, and he said, “This idea seems crazy to me that Susskind could identify the quantum
>   multiverse with the inflationary multiverse. **They are at right angles to each other.”**

What is the meaning of the bold part? Does that mean they are very different?

Comment: Thanks, but please consider [waiting longer before accepting](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/36187). :)

Comment: Oh yes. good point. thank you. I take it back and if nothing better shows up, I would accept your answer again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea. I interpret it to imply disagreement, incompatibility, incongruity, etc. I really can't say that this is common expression, at least in everyday language. But it's understandable. The idea of perpendicularity suggesting dissimilarity is not unprecedented:

> [perpendicular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perpendicular)
>   4 : relating to, uniting, or consisting of individuals of dissimilar type or on different levels
>   (M-W)

You might be able to say Weinberg's expression is a bit of word play, or simply a mathematical metaphor used to express this idea.